# Google Material design is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, material-design

Google Material design is not working in asp.net.
    I added whole thing all files and scripts. but still not working. 
    what should I add any extra thing, help me please.

```
 css: 
    <link href="css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/roboto.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/roboto.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/ripples.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/material-fullpalette.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/material-fullpalette.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="navbar navbar-warning">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-warning-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-warning-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    script:
      <script src="js/ripples.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/ripples.js"></script>
            <script src="js/npm.js"></script>
            <script src="js/material.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/material.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: ripples.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
ripples.js:324 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
npm.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
material.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
material.js:236 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
WebForm1.aspx:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Comment: change order of your js. first attach jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js, after that attach ripples.min.js

Comment: yes sir,    ripples.min.js not loading .

Comment: no sir,    i tried not working, i added jquery.min.js and ui i added first. still not working.

Comment: please make sure your console doesn't show any error

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this order:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ripples.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/npm.js"></script>
```